# post-self-insert-hook throws "Invalid Function"

Tags: elisp

```lisp
(defun foo (aa)
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (setq aa '(+ aa 1))
  ))

(defun bar ()
  (interactive)
  (setq b 6)
  (add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook (foo b)))
```

Instead of incrementing `b`, elisp throws an error: `Invalid function: 7`. It does take `b` as an argument, but only when its equal to 6, it stops working after incrementing. Why? The problem occures with `b` being equal to any number, it always prints message like `Invalid function:b+1`.

Comment: Down-voted on account of the lack of follow-up to prevent the Community bot from bumping it in future, as this question is unlikely to be of use to anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Right now there are far too many problems with your code to address them one by one.

You need to start with learning how Lisp works.

In Emacs, hit <kbd>C-h i</kbd> then click on [Emacs Lisp Intro: (eintr)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html), then keep reading.

Answer (score 0):

As sds says, there are a lot of problems with that code.

```
(defun foo (aa)
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (setq aa '(+ aa 1))
  ))
```

This function briefly sets the variable `aa` (which is its own argument and never seen by anything outside of the function) to the literal quoted form `(+ aa 1)`.  It also returns that same value.  Here `aa` is the symbol `aa` and nothing more.

```
(defun bar ()
  (interactive)
  (setq b 6)
  (add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook (foo b)))
```

`(foo b)` is not a function, and therefore adding it to a hook will result in an error.

`(lambda () (foo b))` is a function which calls `(foo b)`

> elisp throws an error: Invalid function: 7.

Not with the code you've shown, it won't.  Clearly you're evaluating a version in which you *haven't* quoted `(+ aa 1)` in which case `(foo 6)` will actually return `7` and hence you're trying to do this:

```
(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook 7)
```